# Store JSON response as an array to be used in calculations: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, google-apps-script

So I have this javascript code with API that fetches time entries from 10,000 ft project management systems.

I can't seem to figure out how to make this code save the JSON response in an array and calculate the total for each user.

I have also unsuccessfully tried to figure out a way to remove the endpoints from the URL to make it easy to change the options.

```
function fetchSheet(accessToken) {
   var headers = {
      headers: {
         Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
      }
   }
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/time_entries?from=2020-01-07&to=2020-01-08&auth=token=', headers);
   Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you get an error?

Comment: @user1538301 there is no error. I get a response. I just need to store the response in array to enable me to do calculations.

Comment: What does the response look like? We can't help you if we have no idea what kind of data you're working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a global variable using `var`, or, if you need to actually store it for some time, you could save that information using your localStorage like this: `localStorage.setItem("foobar", JSON.stringify(yourArray))`.

When it comes to saving that info in the array, you can change your fetch to something like this:

```
fetch(
  'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/time_entries?from=2020-01-07&to=2020-01-08&auth=token=', 
  headers
).then( res => res.json()).then(data => {
  yourArray = data
})
```

That way, you're converting the response into a JSON so you can store. Just remember, if you want to get that back from the localstorage, use `JSON.parse`, like this:

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("foobar"))`

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to figure out how to make this code save the JSON response in an array and calculate the total for each user.

The response data will likely be a string representation of your array (or possibly a string nested in an object, depending on how `UrlFetchApp` works). You can convert the string back to an array using `JSON.parse()`

> I have also unsuccessfully tried to figure out a way to remove the endpoints from the URL to make it easy to change the options.

```
let getUrl = (from, to) => 
  `https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/time_entries?from=${from}&to=${to}&auth=token=`;
```

or more generic

```js
let getUrl = (endpoint, queryParams) => 
  `${endpoint}?${Object.entries(queryParams).map(kv => kv.join('=')).join('&')}`;
  
console.log(getUrl('google.com', {q: 'my_query', date: 'today', results: 30}));
```